# cakephp authorization error with no identity

Tags: cakephp

I use cakephp 4 with authorization 2 plugin.
I have a policy that check if the user have an "admin" role.

It works fine when a user is identified on the application => the identity is set.

But when the user is not identified => identity is null

the call to the policy return an error :

```
Argument 1 passed to App\Policy\UserPolicy::canAdminAccess() must be an instance of Authorization\IdentityInterface, null given
```

The policy function: ($user is null when not identified)

```
public function canAdminAccess(IdentityInterface $user)
    {
        return (bool)($user->group_id === 1);
        return false;
    }
```

And the call in controller:

```
public function beforeFilter(EventInterface $event)
    {
        parent::beforeFilter($event);
        $this->Authorization->authorize($this->user,'adminAccess');
    }
```

Any idea on how to solve this problem ?

Thanks

Comment: Why does your application allow a non-authenticated user to get that far in the first place?

Comment: @ndm, I don't really undestand your point, how can the applaction disallow the access ? Everybody can call the url ( /admin/mycontroller/myaction). Control is precisely the call to $this->Authorization->authorize($this->user,'adminAccess');

Comment: My point is that an unauthenticated user shouldn't even be able to get to the stage where authorization is checked, naturally the latter depends on the former.

Answer (score 1):

Authorization depends on authentication, when users aren't authenticated then there's usually no point in letting them proceed to the point where authorization checks are being applied.

I would suggest that you consider changing the authentication component's `identityCheckEvent` option from the default `Controller.startup` (happens *after* `Controller::beforeFilter()`) to `Controller.initialize` (this is what invokes `Controller::beforeFilter()`):

```php
$this->loadComponent('Authentication.Authentication', [
    'identityCheckEvent' => 'Controller.initialize',
]);
```

This will check for the identity in the component's `beforeFilter()` callback, which is being invoked before the controller's `beforeFilter()` callback.

Alternatively you can check for the identity yourself in your `beforeFilter()` method:

```php
// ...

if (!$this->Authentication->getIdentity()) {
    throw new UnauthenticatedException(
        $this->Authentication->getConfig('unauthenticatedMessage', '')
    );
}

// ...

$this->Authorization->authorize($this->user, 'adminAccess');
```

Note that for actions that should be allowed to be accessed without authentication, you'd need to make sure to neither apply the authentication check, nor the authorization check! Something like:

```php
$unauthenticatedAllowed = in_array(
    $this->request->getParam('action'),
    $this->Authentication->getUnauthenticatedActions(),
    true
);

// ...

if (!$unauthenticatedAllowed) {
    if (!$this->Authentication->getIdentity()) {
        throw new UnauthenticatedException(
            $this->Authentication->getConfig('unauthenticatedMessage', '')
        );
    }

    // ...

    $this->Authorization->authorize($this->user, 'adminAccess');
}
```

At that point you might also want to ask yourself whether it maybe would make sense to separate the public endpoints from the protected ones, eg put them in separate controllers and/or prefixes, so that you can apply the authentication/authorization middleware only on the protected endpoints, and leave the public ones without any authentication/authorization checks.

See also

- **[Authentication Cookbook > Authentication Component > Configure Automatic Identity Checks](https://book.cakephp.org/authentication/2/en/authentication-component.html#configure-automatic-identity-checks)**

Comment: I already use prefix for admin actions.
I think that checking identification before checking authorization is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

> Argument 1 passed to App\Policy\UserPolicy::canAdminAccess() must be
> an instance of Authorization\IdentityInterface, null given

Where and how did you define `$user` property?

```
public function beforeFilter(EventInterface $event)
    {
        parent::beforeFilter($event);
        debug($this->user); // what is output ??
        //$this->Authorization->authorize($this->user,'adminAccess');

        // to fix, try
        $user = $this->Authentication->getIdentity()->getOriginalData();
        $this->Authorization->authorize($user,'adminAccess');
    }
```

Comment: $user is set in AppController beforeFilter:
By default it is null

if ($this->Authentication->getIdentity()) {
            $identity = $this->Authentication->getIdentity();
            $this->user = $identity->getOriginalData();

....

Comment: When not authenticated, this->Authentication->getIdentity()  return null
So it do not works

Comment: When authentication is not verified, then redirect the request to the login page

Comment: Some parts of the application are open for all without authentication. So in AppController I cannot redirect to login page if not authenticated ...